# Yeoman CRUD Generator not working on MEAN.js

Tags: generator, yeoman, crud, meanjs

Following the instructions on the MEAN.js website, I create a new site and attempt to create a new CRUD using yeoman generator. my command is as follows

```
$ yo meanjs:crud-module meal
```

Everything seems to be created correctly in the modules folder, and when I go tho the site, and attempt to create a new "meal" everything seems to work fine until I hit submit. The browser throws the following error

```
 http://localhost:3000/meals/api/meals 404 (Not Found)
```

Am I missing a step in the setup? is there something additional I need to do to get CRUD to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your routing, check your `client/config/routes` and `server/routes` file. The URL should be:

`http://localhost:3000/api/meals`

without the first meals after 3000. That's why it is a 404.

Hope this helps, if you cant find the problem add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a forward slash(/) in front of api in resource service.
 `/api/meals` instead of `api/meals`